# Why don't Django HTML tags work in strings?

Tags: python, html, django

Lets say I have an image source as such:

```html
<img src="{% static 'images/category1.png' %}">
```

This works completely fine - it finds the image and displays it properly. However, its in a for-loop, so I'm going to have different images for each element (in this case, a different image for each category)

For some reason, this doesn't work:

```html
{% for cat in category %}
...
<img src="{% static 'images/{{cat.category_slug}}.png' %}">
...
{% endfor %}
```

I'm positive that the {{cat.category_slug}} variable has the correct name as my image, as this:

```html
<p>{{cat.category_slug}}</p>
```

shows 'category1' on my site, which is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? Does it give you an error? Or does the image fail to load?

Comment: @Wondercricket: the `+` operator is not implemented in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`|add`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) to perform string concatenation:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/'|add:cat.category_slug|add:'.png' %}">
```

But it might be more elegant to simply make use of of a method in your `Category` model. For example:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128)
    # …

    def get_image(self):
        return f'images/{self.category_slug}.png'
```

then you can implement this as :

```
<img src="{% static cat.get_image %}">
```